# Is there a way to check if a labelbox has been updated in a manner similar to TextBox_AfterUpdate?

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a userform that will allow a user to click on a date in a calendar and update a labelbox on the form with the date (see image attached). I would like to write a code that will check/ensure that the "Week Start" date is always on a Monday, and if not, an error will be displayed and those labels will be cleared.

I have an "Enter" button where I've already coded what I want (see below), but would like to have the error automatically display when the user clicks the wrong date on the calendar.

If there is a way to do this in a manner similar to the TextBox AfterUpdate event, I would be greatly appreciative.

```
'Error message stored in Enter button if work week is selected that does
'not start on a  Monday

If Not Format(datFirstDay, "w") = "2" Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a work week that starts on Monday.")
    lblStartDate.Caption = ""
    lblStopDate.Caption = ""
    LengthNo.Caption = ""
End If
```

[Image of what the form looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEYSt.png)

Comment: No. I suggest you use a TextBox instead of a label, and modify the style of the textbox to make it look like a label

Comment: Using a Label instead of a TextBox isn't good practice.  It will look odd to users.  You can always lock the text box if you don't want users to type dates.  Although I would leave it free form or calendar controlled and validate to ensure it is a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user is selecting the date from the calendar and you are just using the label to display the selected date. It would be helpful to show the code that sets the value of the label. You should associate your error checking with entering the date on the calendar rather than any event related to the label. Talking about events on the label is a red herring.